# $.post data success returning data unsuccessfully, but successfully?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a "like" function in php and jquery and I'm at the last part of it. When I click on the:

```
<a href="#" class = "like" onclick="like_add(<?php echo $post_id ?>);">like</a>
<span id="post_<?php echo $post_id ?>_likes">
    <?php echo $post_likes; ?>
</span>
```

the function in add_like.php:

```
<?php add_like() ?>
```

submits the user data and increments the like count by one in the database.

The problem I'm having is I'm getting an alert that say success in it when it shouldn't be and it doesn't update the like count until I refresh the page. I should be getting a alert that says 'works!' and getting the like count back.

edit**

Right now it is returning the echoed "success" from the like_add.php in the alert when I click on the like button. This to be exact:

'

success'

**like.js**

```
function like_add(post_id){
 $.post('../public/like_add.php', {post_id:post_id}, function(data){
    if (data == 'success') {
        like_get(post_id);
        alert("works!");
    }else{
        alert("'" + data + "'");
    }
 });
}
function like_get(post_id){
 $.post('../public/like_get.php', {post_id:post_id}, function(data){
     $('#post_'+post_id+'_likes').text(data);
 });    
}
```

**add_like.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['post_id'], $_SESSION['user_id']) 
&& post_exists($_POST['post_id'])){

$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

  if (previously_liked($post_id, $user_id) === true) {
    echo "You've already liked this";
  } else{
    add_like($post_id, $user_id);
    echo 'success';
  }
}?>
```

Comment: What exactly is it returning? Put quotes around the data in the alert call, like `alert("'" + data + "'")` to see.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy it's returning in the alert:

    '
    
    
    success'

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing your question with the relevant data, by the way.

Comment: I should be getting a alert that says 'works!' and getting the like count back. >> Where is 'works!' in your code. Then what do you mean by gettign the like count back ...??

Comment: It looks like there is a new line on the return. Try trimming it on the return or finding where that is coming from in the PHP. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: the alert('works!') is in the like.js if statement and I meant returning the like count back into <span id="post_<?php echo $post_id ?>_likes"> <span>

Comment: Hey seems like there is a `\n` or newline character before `success` while returning from the backend. Can you check that out?

Comment: @chris85, You were right the data needs to be trimmed.  if (data.trim() == 'success') {} seemed to fix the problem. Thank you for your wonderful help!

Comment: @ynos1234, it's the strangest thing because I can't find the new line at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have whitespace (like a hard return) before your `<?php` or after your closing `?>` tag, you will return more than "success" as you saw when you alerted `' success'`. Find this whitespace and remove it. Make sure your opening PHP tag is flush against the top left of your script page.

---

As commenters have mentioned, an easy fix is to trim the `data` variable so `' success'` becomes `'success'`;